# read from the nth column on using awk

Tags: bash, awk

The `nmcli -c no device` displays:

```
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp3s0          wifi      connected     My Test Connection
p2p-dev-wlp3s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --         
enp4s0f1        ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo              loopback  unmanaged     --
```

In order to separate the info on wifi, I have this command:

```sh
wf_info="$(nmcli -c no device | grep "wifi[^-]" | awk '{print "wf_devc="$1, "wf_state="$3, "wf_conn="$4}')"
eval "$wf_info"

echo "$wf_devc"   # returns wlp3s0
echo "$wf_state"  # returns connected
echo "$wf_conn"   # returns My (while should be My Test Connection)
```

The problem with the above command is that for *wf_conn* it gives me `My` while I should be the full name `My Test Connection`. How can I tell the command to read from the 4th column on and not just the 4th column for the *wf_conn*?

Comment: You can specify a Field Separator in awk, either by using the `-F` flag or by setting it in the begin block: `-F'\t'` and `BEGIN { FS='\t' }`. I'm not sure if escape sequences in the flag are portable.

Comment: sooo why not start with `nmcli --mode=multiline -c no device wifi`?

Comment: @AndreasLouv So what would the command be?

Comment: @KamilCuk This takes seconds and it's too long because it should be run every two seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "collect" the rest of the fields into a single variable and then print it:

```sh
read wf_devc wf_state wf_conn < <(nmcli -c no device | awk '/wifi[^-]/{r=""; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){r=r (i==4 ? "":" ") $i}; print $1" "$3" "r}')
```

Note that `grep` part is incorporated into `awk`, `/wifi[^-]/` will  make sure only those lines will be printed that contains `wifi` followed by a char other than a `-` char.

The `r=""; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){r=r (i==4 ? "":" ") $i}` part inits an `r` empty string and then all fields starting with Field 4 are concatenated using a space.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/WcGQlb):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp3s0          wifi      connected     My Test Connection
p2p-dev-wlp3s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --         
enp4s0f1        ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo              loopback  unmanaged     --'
read wf_devc wf_state wf_conn < <(awk '
    /wifi[^-]/{
        r=""; 
        for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){
            r=r (i==4 ? "":" ") $i
        }; 
        print $1" "$3" "r
    }' <<< "$s")

echo "wf_devc=$wf_devc wf_state=$wf_state wf_conn=$wf_conn"
```

Output:

```
wf_devc=wlp3s0 wf_state=connected wf_conn=My Test Connection
```